# Phonegap remove title bar at start

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

im new to with phonegap.
Cant remove title bar at start of my app.
The point is that im using phonegap for packaging, but i do not have any androidmanifest.xml file in the project folder, thought i have it in my android sdk tools on the other drive, but still changing 
  `<application   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">` 
gave no result.
To build my app i run  - phonegap run android in my app folder.
Any ideas?? thnx)

Comment: looks like it is impossible

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you are using Cordova and PhoneGap (not PhoneGap-Build).

If that is the case, you need to add:

```
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
```

In your `config.xml` file, in the `res/xml` folder.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/sRLVweSBiMM