# Remove Title Bar Phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, cordova-3

How to remove the title bar that is showing for a second or so at the start of the application in phonegap build?
I tried fullscreen as showed in [Phonegap remove title bar at start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765825/phonegap-remove-title-bar-at-start) and its working, the app is full screen but the title bar stil shows up for a second or so at the start of the app. 
When buildin locally I can remove the title bar form manifest.xml with the command android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">

How can I completely remove the title bar from phonegap build?

I solved it by adding these lines to the config.xml

```
<gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest">

       <supports-screens 
              android:xlargeScreens="false" 
              android:largeScreens="false" 
              android:smallScreens="false" />
        <application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" ></activity>
        </application>
</gap:config-file>
```

Comment: Please! Can somebody share his thoughts on this? I'm sure everybody has this problem and I searched several hours on web without success... Is this problem solved yet? Or it's general?

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue! Is there any way to solve this??

Comment: I added 

[gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest"] 
[application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" ] 
[activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" ][/activity] 
[/application] 
[/gap:config-file] 

to my config.xml -> widget section but its not working. The same as before! Please can anybody share a thought?

Answer (score 9):

Alex already provided the solution in the first post. I'd just like to clarify two things:

1. You don't have to disable support for certain screen sizes for this to work. Note that I've changed the attributes of `supports-screens` back to `true`
2. You need to also provide an android namespace, or PhoneGap Build will complain about a "malformed config.xml" (see the line in bold below)

So this would be your config.xml:

```
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
```

**`xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`**

```
    id        = "com.domain.app"
    version   = "1.0.0">

    ...

    <gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest">
        <supports-screens 
            android:xlargeScreens="true" 
            android:largeScreens="true" 
            android:smallScreens="true" />
        <application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            </activity>
        </application>
    </gap:config-file>
</widget>
```

Hat tip to wildabeast [on github](https://github.com/phonegap/build/issues/24).

Comment: thank you! i suggest removing the fullscreen element like jbelfore says. A big issue for me is when i have that and tap on an input field thats towards the bottom of the screen, the keyboard no longer shows under the input and you can't see what you type.

Comment: BEST ANSWER IN THIS THREAD ! solve the phonegap build title issue

Answer (score 0):

I used robro's code and it worked, but everything on my screen was cut off at the top since I allow the status bar using this setting in my config:

```
<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
```

I then took out the following:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" ></activity>
```

and all looks perfect now.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding splashscreens (if you don't have them already) I tried it and you can no longer see the title bar.

Your config.xml needs these for Android:

```
<icon src="icons/android/ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
<icon src="icons/android/mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
<icon src="icons/android/hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
<icon src="icons/android/xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
```

and then add your images to the src.