# Where to put gap:config-file in PhoneGap config.xml

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I want to hide the title bar on a PhoneGap App that shows quickly when the app starts. I found a solution ([Remove Title Bar Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21884095/remove-title-bar-phonegap)) but when I try to apply it PhoneGap Build tells me that my config.xml has errors.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.phonegap.helloworld" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>Hello World</name>
    <description>
        Hello World sample application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">
        PhoneGap Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.7.0" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />

    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />

    <gap:splash src="splash.png" />

    <gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest">
        <supports-screens 
            android:xlargeScreens="true" 
            android:largeScreens="true" 
            android:smallScreens="true" />
        <application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            </activity>
        </application>
    </gap:config-file>
</widget>
```

It's the last part where its says `<gap:config-file` which should hide the title bar.
Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong? I am new to PhoneGab and doing a lot a copy & paste, yet. But of course I try to understand things.

Comment: did you try this: `<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" ></activity>` and did you also try to write `Fullscreen` instead of `fullscreen`?

Comment: I tried Fullscreen but did not help. <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >, isn't that exactly what I have in my code?

Comment: sry, didn't see that. It is the same

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Also, did you run that xml file through https://validator.w3.org/ ? I suspect your are getting an "undefined error". I see you are missing the Android part of the ```xmlns:android  = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"```  You can check it against my boilerplate5 https://github.com/jessemonroy650/Phonegap--Generic-Boilerplate5

Comment: @JesseMonroy650, xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" was missing in the <widget> part. If you post this as an answer I can accept it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your are getting an "undefined error". I see you are missing the Android part in the first XML element `<widget>`

You should add:

```
xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```